# Is Range download of an older version of a OneDrive file supported using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to use the Graph API to download an older version of a file. I see from the documentation that there is an API to download the contents(/drives/<drive_id>/items/<item_id>/versions/<version_id>/content). But unlike for driveItem, I did not find a downloadUrl for an older version of the file using which we could do range/partial downloads. Is there a way to do partial download of an older version of the file?

Answer (score 0):

That API will return a `302` redirect, and so if you pull the `Location` header out of that response and use it in conjunction with a `Range` header you should be able to get a partial response. If the library you're using automatically follows the redirect, and you have no ability to stop it from doing so, you may find that adding the `Range` header to the request to `/content` will end up having the header automatically attached when the follow occurs, but that'll depend on the implementation of the client.

Comment: I had tried that already and the Range header was not taking effect. I retried now(taking the Location from the 302 response and sending a GET request with the Range header) and I see the same behaviour. The entire content is getting downloaded. Just to make sure I am using the correct header name and value below is an example:
Range: bytes=0-100

Comment: That seems strange, and your header looks correct. Could you provide an example URL that's ignoring the `Range` header? Feel free to obfuscate the domain and ids

Comment: https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/personal/test_domain_com/_api/v2.0/drives/b!tirnaBg3REOXeyngu1vNPhFDnlKvUzJBvTYnDbLZcrmLvjRZYLXTQJCVhD8QxPIt/items/013YQ5J3QGX7Y4DDFJQZA35D7ETUHBWGZ2/versions/3.0/streamContent?tempauth=<temp_auth>. Removed the tempauth as it was exceeding the character limit allowed in comment. Looks like the streamContent api is not honouring the Range header.

Comment: Hi Brad, can you let me know if this is something which is being worked upon to fix?